# How to get all liked movie pages of a user

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Is it possible to get all liked movie pages via FQL?

Answer (score 3):

The most *stable* way currently to get the *names* of the pages not necessarily the ids would be to run a query on the user table. `page_fan` returns little to no results even though the user may have numerous pages likes of type `Movie`.

`SELECT movies from user where uid=me() and movies != ''`

or for all friends

`SELECT movies from user where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) and movies != ''`

There is currently no way to get all like movie pages of a user (in terms of ids) via FQL.

*Update*: I jumped the gun.

This should work

`SELECT name, page_id from page where page_id in (SELECT page_id from page_fan where uid in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) and profile_section='movies')`

Though it's still unstable and doesn't return all matches >.<

Answer (score 1):

yes, just query the FQL page_fan table http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/ with the correct permissions.

Comment: This returns incomplete data or no data at all.

Comment: yep, welcome to developing for Facebook.  Something that works an hour ago is not guaranteed to work an hour from now.  It's been 3 months since I wrote the answer...so the probability is high that it won't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.  Check out the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).  You can run FQL statements on the `page_fan` table from there. You'll need to require the [`user_likes` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) and then parse out the movie entries.  *that field is not index*.